# Undefined reference in libfreenect c++ wrapper

Tags: c++, cmake, openkinect

I want to print the number of connected devices with libfreenect in c++. As described in https://openkinect.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Wrapper
i include the libfreenect.hpp header file in my TestKinectConnection.cpp.

My TestKinectConnection.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libfreenect.hpp"

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    Freenect::Freenect nect;
    freenect_context *f_ctx;
    cout << nect.deviceCount() << endl;
    return(0);
}
```

When i build with `cmake --build build -- -j3` the terminal shows

```
CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/src/main/TestKinectConnection.cpp.o: In function `Freenect::Freenect::Freenect()':
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8FreenectC2Ev[_ZN8Freenect8FreenectC5Ev]+0x40): undefined reference to `freenect_init'
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8FreenectC2Ev[_ZN8Freenect8FreenectC5Ev]+0x90): undefined reference to `freenect_select_subdevices'
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8FreenectC2Ev[_ZN8Freenect8FreenectC5Ev]+0xb0): undefined reference to `pthread_create'
CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/src/main/TestKinectConnection.cpp.o: In function `Freenect::Freenect::~Freenect()':
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8FreenectD2Ev[_ZN8Freenect8FreenectD5Ev]+0xa5): undefined reference to `pthread_join'
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8FreenectD2Ev[_ZN8Freenect8FreenectD5Ev]+0xb4): undefined reference to `freenect_shutdown'
CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/src/main/TestKinectConnection.cpp.o: In function `Freenect::Freenect::deviceCount()':
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8Freenect11deviceCountEv[_ZN8Freenect8Freenect11deviceCountEv]+0x17): undefined reference to `freenect_num_devices'
CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/src/main/TestKinectConnection.cpp.o: In function `Freenect::Freenect::operator()()':
TestKinectConnection.cpp:(.text._ZN8Freenect8FreenectclEv[_ZN8Freenect8FreenectclEv]+0x4f): undefined reference to `freenect_process_events_timeout'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/build.make:95: recipe for target '../bin/projektinf' failed
make[2]: *** [../bin/projektinf] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/projektinf.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Specify the minimum version for CMake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# Project's name
project(projektinf)

# Set the output folder where your program will be created
set(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})
set(EXTERNAL_INSTALL_LOCATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

# The following folder will be included
include_directories("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include")

add_executable(projektinf ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/main/TestKinectConnection.cpp)

add_library(libfreenect ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/include/libfreenect.hpp)
target_link_libraries(projektinf PUBLIC libfreenect)
set_target_properties(libfreenect PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
```

https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/wrappers/cpp/libfreenect.hpp

https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/blob/master/include/libfreenect.h

In short summary, libfreenect.hpp tries to include libfreenect.h und completely fails.

Comment: Regarding `pthread_join` problem use the [`FindThreads`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindThreads.html) module and link with `Threads::Threads`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it is unclear whether you installed libfreenect globally or simply bundled the library with your code.

If you installed it globally, you forgot to tell CMake that the `libfreenect` target needs to link with `libfreenect.so` using the `-lfreenect` linker flag.
Adding the following should fix that:

```
set_property(TARGET libfreenect PROPERTY INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES -lfreenect)
```

The proper approach is to make `libfreenect` an IMPORTED target, as documented in ["It's time to do CMake right"](https://pabloariasal.github.io/2018/02/19/its-time-to-do-cmake-right/).

If you bundled the `.cpp` with your code, you need to add the `.cpp` file to the `add_library` statement that defines the `libfreenect` target.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's the advice i needed.